# Groovy - Stackoverflow whilst calling super.method()

Tags: groovy

I have had an issue whilst overriding a method in Groovy whilst changing the return type (covariant).

My test code is:

```
class Grandparent {
    public Grandparent doStuff( String s ){
        println "GP $s"
        this
    }
}

class Parent extends Grandparent{
    public Parent doStuff( String s ){
        println "P $s "
        this
    }
}

class Child extends Parent{
    public Child doStuff( String s ){
        println "C $s "
        super.doStuff(s)
        this
    }
}

Child c = new Child()
c.doStuff("Yo")
```

In the above script, the code stackoverflows and just repeatedly invokes the doStuff() method on the Child class:

```
Caught: java.lang.StackOverflowError
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at Child.doStuff(GroovyInheritanceTest.groovy:18)
    at Child.doStuff(GroovyInheritanceTest.groovy)
    at Parent.doStuff(GroovyInheritanceTest.groovy)
    at Child.super$3$doStuff(GroovyInheritanceTest.groovy)
    at Child.doStuff(GroovyInheritanceTest.groovy:18)
    at Child.doStuff(GroovyInheritanceTest.groovy)
    at Parent.doStuff(GroovyInheritanceTest.groovy)
```

This problem does not happen if

1) we have just two classes in the heirarchy (e.g. cut out Child)
2) all instances of doStuff return the same type e.g. all return GradParent

I am using Groovy 2.1.5  - It does appear to be working in Groovy 2.2.

Does anyone know if there is a workaround to make this work in Groovy 2.1.5 or have details of a bug number that this was fixed as part of?

Comment: It also works fine with groovy 2.3.3.

Comment: I got bitten by that one sometime ago and could not upgrade groovy. Luckily, i could change the subclass method name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know if there is a workaround to make this work in Groovy
>   2.1.5 or have details of a bug number that this was fixed as part of?

See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-5810 and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-6818.

Comment: Thanks - this particular code example actually works in 2.2 (the first bug relates to static methods, second bug looks very similar but is reported as broken in 2.2). Excepting answer as useful none the less.